# Safari pages show up blurry

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, font, resolution

I've been using chrome for a while on my MacBook pro 2019 (4 thunderbolt USB-c) and have on multiple occasions wanted to start using safari because of the high CPU-usage of chrome. The reason I've refrained from doing so is the extremely low resolution that safari renders in. This affects **everything** from text fonts to images as you can see in the example below. Reading text from a retina screen at this low resolution literally gives me headache and renders safari unusable.

I've looked around on quite a bit but I have only found solutions for specific websites so I will reiterate: the issue occurs **only** in safari (no other apps whatever), on my main display and with **all content** displayed. No plugins.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

[image: Left is safari, right is chrome. Standard zoom]

[image: A zoom-in of the original rendering resolution in safari.]